# How do I flag a post as a duplicate?

Tags: support, flags

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475948/reterving-the-users-name-then-storing-it-in-the-local-storage) is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage). However, I can't seem to find a button to report the post. How do I report posts that are obvious duplicates?

Comment: You need 15 reputation for that privilege: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: When you have enough reputation, use the `flag` link under the question; you'll be asked for a link or id of the possible duplicate.

Comment: You now have 13 rep. One approved edit will be enough to get the flagging privilege. Find a post with poor formatting, grammar, and/or spelling and get to work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Rizier123 mentioned, the flagging privilege requires [15 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). You currently have 13 reputation.

If you want to earn the privilege fast, you can do a post edit. One approved edit will be enough to get you up to 15 rep. Find a post with poor formatting, grammar, and/or spelling and get to work!

As @alttag mentioned, the `flag` link will appear under the question once you gain the privilege, and you will need to provide "a link or id of the possible duplicate".